# Solving multivariable trig Identities

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I'm trying to solve for a certain set of trig identities in terms of other trig identities. I saw [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11855/solving-trig-identities-in-specific-terms) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/434/how-to-express-trigonometric-equation-in-terms-of-of-given-trigonometric-functio?noredirect=1&lq=1), but in my example, I have two tries:

```
Solve[{al == Sin[b] Cos[a], 
  am == Sin[b] Sin[a], an == Cos[b]}, 
 Cos[b], {a, b}]
```

```
Solve[{am == Sin[b] Sin[a], an == Cos[b]}, 
 Cos[b], {a, b}]
```

In the first example, I get a null solution. In the second, Mathematica recognizes that the expression is just 'an'. Apparently I need to building the rule set up from scratch for solve to use, any suggestions here? The actual expressions I plan to use will be more complex, so it failing here isn't giving me much confidence... In the meantime, I'll be trying to generalize the Weierstrass approach.

Edit:

A fuller example might be:

```
Solve[{al == Sin[b] Cos[a], 
  am == Sin[b] Sin[a], an == Cos[b]}, 
 Sin[b] Cos[a] + Cos[b]^2, {a, b}]
```

Giving the result

```
al+an^2
```

Comment: `Reduce[{al == Sin[b] Cos[a], am == Sin[b] Sin[a], an == Cos[b]}, {a, 
  b}]`?

Comment: I'm not understanding the 2nd argument in all of your examples for `Solve`.  Why do you include `Cos[b]` and `Sin[b] Cos[a] + Cos[b]^2` as the 2nd argument?

Comment: @JimB I'm referring to [this example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108328/rewriting-expression-in-terms-of-factor)

Comment: Thanks.  I see (now) what is done in that example.  (I'm still looking for that format in the `Solve` documentation but don't see it.  But that's my problem, not yours.)

Comment: The 3rd example doesn't work in _v12.3_ and _v14.0_, which version did you use?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can not solve for a function of a variable (b in the first example) and at the same time try to eliminate that variable. Eliminate the other variables or functions of that.

Solutions to the first example

```
Solve[{al == Sin[b] Cos[a], am == Sin[b] Sin[a], an == Cos[b]}, 
 Cos[b], {Sin[a], Sin[b], Cos[a]}]
```

Don't know why second example works, it should not.

Third example: give the expression you are looking for a name and solve for that, eliminating other functions.

```
Solve[{al == Sin[b] Cos[a], am == Sin[b] Sin[a], an == Cos[b], 
  fin == Sin[b] Cos[a] + Cos[b]^2}, fin, {Sin[a], Cos[a], Sin[b], 
  Cos[b]}]

(*  {{fin -> al + an^2}}    *)
```