# how can tangent half angle substitution be done in Mathematica?

Tags: replacement, trigonometry

Is it possible to replace sine and cosine in terms of tangent half-angles and again the tangent half-angles by a variable say `t`?

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/440/34) is based on tangent half-angle substitutions.

Answer (score 5):

Define your rules:

```
rule = {Cos[_] :> (1 - t^2)/(1 + t^2), Sin[_] :> 2*t/(1 + t^2)};
Sin[x] /. rule
Sin[x] /. rule /. t -> Tan[x/2] // Simplify
```

> $\dfrac{2 t}{t^2+1}$
>
> $\sin(x)$

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest something like this

```
 rule = {
     Cos[x_] :> (1 - tan[x/2]^2)/(1 + tan[x/2]^2),
     Sin[x_] :> 2 tan[x/2]/(1 + tan[x/2]^2)};

 Sin[x]/.rule -> (2 tan[x/2])/(1 + tan[x/2]^2)
```

Note the lowercase `tan`. This will not simplify to other trig functions on you unless you replace with the real `Tan`:

```
  Sin[x]/.rule /. tan[x_]:>Tan[x] //fullSimplify -> Sin[x]
```

This way you carry around the original argument:

otherwise you get behavior like this:

```
   Sin[x]-Sin[y] /. Sin[_] :> 2*t/(1 + t^2)
```

> 0

Comment: you'd get the same result with Öska's answer. Try his `Sin[x] - Sin[y] /. rule`.

Comment: that was my point, that answer is potentially dangerous unless obviously you take care all your `Sin`,`Cos`'s have the same argument. (in which case you may as well do `rule=Sin(x)-> ... ).