# Is there a way to rewrite integrals in Mathematica using u substitution?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

In Mathematica, can I give it an integral and a few substitution rules and have it rewrite the integral in terms of those variables?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html)

Comment: @MarkMcClure I tried but it wouldn't let me make an account there. Also I don't want to post my integral because it's homework-related and don't want people to solve it for me. I just want to know how to verify my work with u-sub so I know I'm doing it properly manually.

Comment: @Darksonn I tried it but it didn't work. I did Replace[Integrate[my integral stuff here], {my rules here}]

Comment: @user176201 What about defining the things you're replacing as variables? http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/VariablesAndFunctions.html

Comment: @Darksonn My rules look like {w-x -> u}. Right now I am using Wolfram online so maybe it isn't the same as Mathematica.

Comment: What about something like `F[w_] := 5+3*(w-x)` and then calling it as `F[u+x]`

Comment: I am sure "user" wants something that will replace both the integrand and the $dx$ automatically.  And the limits of integration in a definite integral.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a naive start.  It will probably work on most calculus course material, but `Solve` is not guaranteed to invert every possible substitution.  (For instance, it does not check the domain of integration in substitution of trigonometric functions, so it should not be hard to come up with an example where it does not work.)  I have always wished there were something built into *Mathematica* for doing this -- that is to say, a user-interface for such transformations.

There are two ways to do a substitution, let $x = g(u)$ or $u = h(x)$.  And there are two kinds of integrals, definite and indefinite.  Hence four somewhat similar functions.

```
ClearAll[substitute];
SetAttributes[substitute, HoldAll];

substitute[Integrate[f_, x_], u_ -> gx_] := 
  With[{sub = First@Solve[u == gx, x] /. _C -> 0},
   With[{integrand = (f /. sub) D[x /. sub, u]},
    Defer@Integrate[integrand, u]]
   ];
substitute[Integrate[f_, x_], {u_, sub : (x_ -> gu_)}] := 
  With[{integrand = (f /. sub) D[gu, u]},
   Defer@Integrate[integrand, u]
   ];
substitute[Integrate[f_, {x_, x1_, x2_}], u_ -> gx_] := 
  With[{sub = First@Solve[u == gx, x] /. _C -> 0},
   With[{integrand = (f /. sub) D[x /. sub, u], 
     u1 = gx /. x -> x1, 
     u2 = gx /. x -> x2},
    Defer@Integrate[integrand, {u, u1, u2}]
    ]];
substitute[Integrate[f_, {x_, x1_, x2_}], {u_, sub : (x_ -> gu_)}] := 
 With[{integrand = (f /. sub) D[gu, u], 
   u1 = u /. First@Solve[gu == x1, u], 
   u2 = u /. First@Solve[gu == x2, u]},
  Defer@Integrate[integrand, {u, u1, u2}]
  ]
```

Some simple examples:

```
substitute[Integrate[x Exp[x^2], x], u -> x^2]
(* Integrate[E^u/2, u] *)

substitute[Integrate[Sin[x] Exp[Cos[x]], x], u -> Cos[x]]
(* Integrate[-E^u, u] *)

substitute[Integrate[Sin[x] Exp[Cos[x]], x], {u, x -> ArcCos[u]}]
(* Integrate[-E^u, u] *)

substitute[Integrate[Sin[x] Exp[Cos[x]], {x, 0, Pi/2}], u -> Cos[x]]
(* Integrate[-E^u, {u, 1, 0}] *)

substitute[Integrate[Sin[x] Exp[Cos[x]], {x, 0, Pi/2}], {u, x -> ArcCos[u]}]
(* Integrate[-E^u, {u, 1, 0}] *)
```

Answer (score 5):

In *v13.1* [`IntegrateChangeVariables`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegrateChangeVariables.html) is introduced.

Answer (score 4):

**2022 Update: Included in Mathematica 13.1**

As briefly stated in [xzczd answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/270116/41148), after eight years, this function was explicitly added to [Mathematica v13.1](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2022/06/launching-version-13-1-of-wolfram-language-mathematica/) with the new function [IntegrateChangeVariables](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegrateChangeVariables.html).

Here is how to perform the same five integral substitutions as in [michael-e2 answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59898/41148) with the new `Mathematica` function:

```
int1 = Inactive[Integrate][x Exp[x^2], x];
IntegrateChangeVariables[int1, u, u == x^2]
(* Integrate[E^u/2, u] *)

int2 = Inactive[Integrate][Sin[x] Exp[Cos[x]], x];
IntegrateChangeVariables[int2, u, u == Cos[x]]
(* Integrate[-E^u, u, Assumptions -> -1 <= u <= 1 && 0 <= x <= Pi *)

IntegrateChangeVariables[int2, u, x == ArcCos[u]]
(* Integrate[-E^u, u] *)

int3 = Inactive[Integrate][Sin[x] Exp[Cos[x]], {x, 0, Pi/2}];
IntegrateChangeVariables[int3, u, u == Cos[x]]
(* Integrate[-E^u, {u, 0, 1}] *)

IntegrateChangeVariables[int3, u, x == ArcCos[u]]
(* Integrate[-E^u, {u, 0, 1}] *)
```

Comment: This seems like it would be a good addition to the existing community wiki answer.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the Mathematica substitution operator:
$f(x)/.\{x\rightarrow u\}$
returns $f(u)$.

Suppose you want to substitute $\cos x = u$, you can write out your integrand on one line then put  $/.\{x\rightarrow \textrm{ArcCos}[u]\}$ after it. Bear in mind you will also need to fix the differential factor: $\sin x dx \rightarrow du$

Answer (score 1):

For example, ReleaseHold[x^2 HoldForm[D[x,u]]/.x->ArcCos[u]]
gives
$$-\frac{ArcCos[u]^2}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}.$$

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with integrals

Comment: If I surround all of this with Integrate[...,u], it works for me. You should really be asking this on Mathematica.se

Comment: I don't understand your example? It just shows x^2 and arccos(u) etc? Can you use a simpler example?

Comment: How much simpler could it be? If you want to compute $\int x^2\,dx$ using the substitution $u = \cos x$ (I realize you wouldn't do this), write in Mathematica Integrate[ReleaseHold[x^2 HoldForm[D[x,u]]/.x->ArcCos[u]],u] and then resubstitute for $u$.

Comment: Well, I don't see why you can't adapt what I did to that case, using w-x->u.

Answer (score 1):

I have extended @Michael E2 's answer so that it should (hopefully) play nice with some trig substitutions, namely those involving a Weierstrass substitution. The idea is that I get rid of the annoying trig functions in my integrals by replacing with the usual $t=\tan\frac{x}{2}$ substitution first then let the user define their own custom function of $t$ which then uses the code above.

using [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7799/mathematica-sec-and-csc?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/434/how-to-express-trigonometric-equation-in-terms-of-of-given-trigonometric-functio) post as a guide

```
$TrigFns = {Sin, Cos, Tan, Csc, Sec, Cot};
tansubs = Replace[$TrigFns, x_ -> x[_], 2] -> (Through[$TrigFns[x]] /. x -> 2 ArcTan[t] // TrigExpand // Together) // Thread
$Assumptions = _ \[Element] Reals;
ClearAll[wsSubstitute,trigSubstitute,t];
SetAttributes[{wsSubstitute,trigSubstitute}, HoldAll];

wsSubstitute[Integrate[f_, x_], t_] := (f //. tansubs) 2/(1 + t^2) // Simplify;

trigSubstitute[Integrate[f_, x_], u_ -> gt_] := With[{integrand = wsSubstitute[Integrate[f, x], t]}, substitute[Integrate[integrand, t], u -> gt]];
trigSubstitute[Integrate[f_, x_], {u_, sub : (t_ -> gu_)}] := With[{integrand = wsSubstitute[Integrate[f, x], t]}, substitute[Integrate[integrand, t], {u, sub}]];
```

As a couple examples of its usage, I will first simply do a couple Weierstrass substitutions from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution):

```
trigSubstitute[Integrate[1/(Cos[x] + 2), x], t -> t]
trigSubstitute[Integrate[1/(a Cos[x] + b Sin[x] + c), x], t -> t]
```

> $$\int \frac{2}{t^2+3} \, dt$$
>   $$\int \frac{2}{-a t^2+a+2 b t+c t^2+c} \, dt$$

And as a slightly harder example:

```
trigSubstitute[Integrate[1/(Sqrt[Cos[x] - a] Sqrt[Cos[x] - b]), x], {u, t -> Sqrt[(1 - a)/(1 + a)] Sin[u]}]
```

> $$\int \frac{2 \sqrt{\frac{1-a}{a+1}} \cos (u)}{\sqrt{-\frac{(1-a) \sin ^2(u)}{a+1}-a \left(\frac{(1-a) \sin ^2(u)}{a+1}+1\right)+1} \sqrt{-b \left(\frac{(1-a) \sin ^2(u)}{a+1}+1\right)-\frac{(1-a) \sin ^2(u)}{a+1}+1}} \, du$$

**EDIT:**  Add a `//Simplify` in the expressions for the integrand in the functions `substitute` to make the output nicer.

Answer (score 1):

David Parks's *Presentations* add-on application includes a number of functions for doing indefinite integration step-by-step. For example:

```
<< Presentations`

     integrate[Sin[x] Exp[Cos[x]], x]
(* output displays as the original intregral *)

     % // ChangeIntegralVariable[subrule = u -> Cos[x], x]
(* output displays as integral of -e^u du *)

     % /. IntegralConstantRule
(* output displays as - (integral of e^u du) *)

     % + C // UseIntegralTable[BasicIntegralTable]
(* C - E^u *)

     % /. subrule
(* C - E^Cos[x] *)
```

Comment: How to get this useful package？

Comment: A free version, "Free Presentations", lacking the documentation, is downloadable at http://web.archive.org/web/20151002151440/http://home.comcast.net/~djmpark/DrawGraphicsPage.html. There is also a link there to the full version, including documentation, but I don't know whether the author still responds.