# Expansion for Modified Bessel Function Around Infinity

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, special-functions, complex, series-expansion

I'm somewhat new to Mathematica, and I don't understand why I'm getting inconsistent series expansions for the modified Bessel Function of first kind near $x=\infty$.

**First problem:**
I get different expansions if I multiply the modified Bessel function by any constant:

```
Series[BesselI[0,x],{x, ∞, 0}]
```

> $$ e^{-x} \left(O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^0\right)+e^{2 x}
>    \left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi
>    }}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^1\right)\right)\right) $$

```
Series[2 BesselI[0,x],{x, ∞, 0}]
```

> $$ e^{-x} \left(e^{2 x} \left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}
>    \sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{3/2}\right)\right)+\left(i
>    \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}
>    \sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{3/2}\right)\right)\right) $$

**Second problem:**
Even for $x \in \Re$, the expansion always gives me an imaginary component, for any order of my expansion. This is clearly wrong. For example:

```
Series[BesselI[0, x], {x, ∞, 3}]
```

> $$ e^{-x} \left(e^{2 x} \left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi
>    }}+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{3/2}}{8 \sqrt{2 \pi }}+\frac{9
>    \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{5/2}}{128 \sqrt{2 \pi
>    }}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{7/2}\right)\right)+\left(\frac{i
>    \sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}-\frac{i \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{3/2}}{8 \sqrt{2
>    \pi }}+\frac{9 i \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{5/2}}{128 \sqrt{2 \pi
>    }}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{7/2}\right)\right)\right) $$

Is there a problem with Mathematica, or I am misunderstanding how `Series` works? For the reference, I'm using Mathematica 10.3.0.0.

Thanks!

Comment: "for $x\in\mathbb R$" - you are assuming that, but *Mathematica* assumes all variables are complex unless told otherwise (e.g. via `Assuming[]`).

Comment: what I mean is that, if you evaluate that expression with $x \in \Re$, you get a complex number, which is obviously wrong. And if I explicitly include "Assumptions->x>0", I still get the same expansion.

Comment: I see what you mean now after doing my own tests. That is bizarre indeed.

Answer (score 2):

I am using `13.2.0`

> **First problem**: I get different expansions if I multiply the modified Bessel function by any constant:

```
a1 = Series[BesselI[0, x], {x, ∞, 0}] // Normal;
a2 = Series[2 BesselI[0, x], {x, ∞, 1}] // Normal;
a3 = 2 Series[BesselI[0, x], {x, ∞, 0}] // Normal;
FullSimplify@{a2 - a3, a2 - 2 a1}
```

> [image: res1]

> **Second problem:**
> Even for $x \in \Re$, the expansion always gives me an imaginary component, for any order of my expansion. This is clearly wrong.

A potential workaround -albeit not automatic and pretty

Consider

$$
\begin{equation}
I_n(x) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int^{\pi}_0 d\theta e^{x \cos\theta}\cos(n\theta)
\end{equation}
$$

After the changes of variables, $t=\sqrt{x}\theta$ and $u=\tfrac{t^2}{2}$ [**`the above can be re-written as`**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2791588/leading-terms-in-asymptotic-expansion-of-modified-bessel-function-of-the-first-k) and some massaging we end up having:

$$
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{x} \pi e^{-x} I_{n}(x) = \int^{\infty}_0 du \frac{1}{\sqrt{2u}} e^{-u} \left(1 + \frac{u^2}{6x} - n^2 \frac{u}{x} + \texttt{stuff} \right)
\end{equation}
$$

Mathematica is now happy to do the integral

```
Integrate[(1/
    Sqrt[2 u] Exp[-u] (1 - (n^2 u)/x + u^2/(
      6 x)(*+more stuff relevant for ≠ 0*))) /. n -> 0, {u, 0, 
  Infinity}]// Expand
```

> [image: res2]

I am uncertain how you can impose these changes of variables automatically in `Mathematica`. Not sure if there's even a way to do it.

[**`Michael E2`**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59820/is-there-a-way-to-rewrite-integrals-in-mathematica-using-u-substitution/59898#59898) has written a nice code that does substitutions in the integrand, and you might want to experiment a bit with that.

Since, `v13.1.0` we also have at our disposal [**`IntegrateChangeVariables`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegrateChangeVariables.html) which can be used in this case, however, some manual manipulations are still needed.