# Change integration variable

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Are there any automated procedures to change integration variables?  For example by changing `Sin[u]->x`, I can change

```
Integrate[f[Sin[u]], {u, 0, Pi/2}]
```

into

```
Integrate[f[x]/Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to rewrite integrals in Mathematica using u substitution?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59820/is-there-a-way-to-rewrite-integrals-in-mathematica-using-u-substitution)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a possibly quite naive implementation:

```
changeVariables[expr_, oldVar_, changeFunc_, newVar_, interval_] := With[{
    inverse = InverseFunction @ changeFunc,
    der = D[changeFunc @ oldVar, oldVar]
  },
  {
    (expr /. changeFunc @ oldVar -> newVar) / (
      der /. oldVar -> inverse @ newVar
    ),
    {newVar, changeFunc @ interval[[1]], changeFunc @ interval[[2]]}
  }
]
```

which gives the expected result, in at least simple circumstances:

[image]

Of course, as the warning reminds us, this method uses inverse functions and may, therefore, give incorrect results in some circumstances.
Already in my second example had I used as integration interval $(-\infty,\infty)$ I would have got a wrong result.

Comment: Mathematica will rarely  (if ever)  change the variable of integration in integrals it cannot evaluate.  Your function could be very useful in such cases. Thanks

Comment: Very useful function.+1

Answer (score 4):

In *v13.1* [`IntegrateChangeVariables`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegrateChangeVariables.html) is introduced:

```
IntegrateChangeVariables[Inactive[Integrate][f[Sin[u]], {u, 0, Pi/2}],
  x, x == Sin[u]]
(* Inactive[Integrate][f[x]/Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, 0, 1}] *)
```

[image]

But this function is still marked as EXPERIMENTAL and a bit fragile, so, watch your step :) :

```
(* This gives incorrect result: *)
IntegrateChangeVariables[Inactive[Integrate][f[Sin[u]], {u, 0, Pi/2}], 
  x, Sin[u] == x]
(* Inactive[Integrate][f[Sin[x]], {x, 0, π/2}] *)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, not allowed to comment on glS' answer.
I found the following useful, which builds a rule to change variables in (all!) integrals, building on `changeVariables` above:

```
changeVariableRule[changeFunc_, 
  newVar_] := (Integrate[expr_, {x_, start_, stop_}] :> 
   Integrate @@ 
    changeVariables[expr, x, changeFunc, newVar, {start, stop}])
```