# Substitution into integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, replacement, integral-equations

I have to do a substitution (`u = pi/2-x`) into an definite integral, which I have defined as `f[u]`. When I evaluate my code, no result is produced.

The code I have written is

```
substitute[Integrate[f[u], x], {x, 0, Pi/2}], u -> pi/2-x]
```

Is there something I am missing in my code that I am unaware of?

My `f[u]`is `((Sin[x])^n/(Cos[x])^n + (Sin[x])^n)`. and I am trying to substitute  `u = u = pi/2-x` into` it.

Comment: There is no Mathematica command `substitute` (look at documentation for [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html)). `pi` should be `Pi` (all built-in symbols start with a capital letter). Pattern [`Blank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html)(`_`) is only used on LHS of function definition not when using the function. What is the definition of your function `f`?

Comment: f is (Sin^n)[x_]/((Cos^n)[x_] + (Sin^n)[x_])

Comment: On a previous question you were told that `Sin^n` and `Cos^n` are the wrong syntax and shown the proper syntax. Edit your question to include the definition of `f` using the proper syntax. Also edit to make best effort to correct other issue that have been pointed out.

Comment: It's not the first time I see someone trying to use the nonexistent function `substitute`. (Someone even posts answer using `substitute`! ) What textbook are you guys refering to?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59820/is-there-a-way-to-rewrite-integrals-in-mathematica-using-u-substitution

Comment: If you're using the `substitute` function defined in my answer, then a proper syntax is `substitute[Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, Pi/2}], u -> pi/2 - x]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to solve for x with respect to u then name it y then substitute with it because your original function f[x] depend on x there's only x

```
f[x_] := ((Sin[x])^(n)/(Cos[x])^(n)) + (Sin[x]^n)

y = x /. Solve[u == (pi/2) - x, x] /. Rule -> Equal


final = Integrate[f[x], x, {x, 0, Pi/2}] /. x -> y
```

[image]

Comment: I guess the OP doesn't care that your answer still contains a `u`, even though the only parameters in the original problem are `pi` and `n` (although `pi` might be a typo for `Pi`).  Note that your integrate code is equivalent to $\int \int _0^{\frac{\pi }{2}}f(x) \, dx \, dx$. I doubt that's the right way to interpret the OP's syntax error.