# Writing a trigonometric expression in terms of another

Tags: expression-manipulation, trigonometry

This is related to [another question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/434/how-to-express-trigonometric-equation-in-terms-of-of-given-trigonometric-functio), in which one wants to rewrite a function of a single variable in terms of another function of that variable. Here I have a function of multiple variables. I want to rewrite the following complex trigonometric expression

```
(-1 + 3 Cos[A]^2) (-1 + 3 Cos[a]^2) + Cos[B - b] Sin[2A] Sin[2a] +
  Cos[2(B - b)] Sin[A]^2 Sin[a]^2
```

in terms of the trigonometric expression

```
Cos[A] Cos[a] + Cos[B - b] Sin[A] Sin[a]
```

How can I do that in Mathematica?

Comment: Also related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3822/can-i-simplify-an-expression-into-form-which-uses-my-own-definitions

Comment: @yohbs I need to know that how can I use that method for multiple variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is not a unique solution to your question, one solution is obtained as follows.

```
(-1 + 3 Cos[A]^2) (-1 + 3 Cos[a]^2) + Cos[B - b] Sin[2 A] Sin[2 a] + 
    Cos[2 (B - b)] Sin[A]^2 Sin[a]^2
```

First, expand functions involving double angles.

```
% /. Sin[2 z_] -> 2 Sin[z] Cos[z] /. Cos[2 z_] -> 1 - 2 Cos[z]^2
(* (-1 + 3 Cos[a]^2) (-1 + 3 Cos[A]^2) + 4 Cos[a] Cos[A] Cos[b - B] Sin[a] Sin[A] + 
    (-1 + 2 Cos[b - B]^2) Sin[a]^2 Sin[A]^2 *)
```

Next designate the new variable as, for instance, `x`, and solve for `Cos[b - B]` as a function of `x`.

```
Flatten@Solve[Cos[A] Cos[a] + Cos[B - b] Sin[A] Sin[a] == x, Cos[B - b]]
(* {Cos[b - B] -> (x - Cos[a] Cos[A]) Csc[a] Csc[A]} *)
```

Finally, eliminate `Cos[b - B]` from the original expression.

```
Collect[%% /. %, x, FullSimplify]
(* 2 x^2 + 1/2 Cos[2 a] (1 + 3 Cos[2 A]) - Sin[A]^2 *)
```

as requested.  Note, however, that `a` or `A` also could have been eliminated, although the resulting expression would have been much more complicated.